# Return Another Function on Ajax Success

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hi everyone ,
             I'm getting some values from html page for printing a form and some values from api , while print buttons clicks i'm calling print function , in that print function i'm calling API values too using AJAX ,with ajax values form not printing bcoz api take time to load database and then i wrote printing function inside the ajax success here also not working can anyone please help me..

```
        function myFunction() {

       var jobcard_id=document.getElementById('jobcard_id').value;
       var vehicle_num1=document.getElementById('veh-numbr1').value;
       var vehicle_num2=document.getElementById('veh-numbr2').value;
       var vehicle_num3=document.getElementById('veh-numbr3').value;
       var vehicle_num4=document.getElementById('veh-numbr4').value;
       var vehicle_number=vehicle_num1+" "+vehicle_num2+" "+vehicle_num3+" "+vehicle_num4;
       var cust_name=document.getElementById('cust_name').value;
       var cont_num=document.getElementById('cont_num').value;
       var cont_addr=document.getElementById('cont_addr').value;
       var brand=document.getElementById('brand').value;
       var model=document.getElementById('model').value;
       var kms=document.getElementById('kms').value;
       var toolkit_availability=document.getElementById('toolkit_availability').value;
       if(toolkit_availability == "True"){ var tol_kit= 'Yes';}else{var tol_kit='No';}           
       var fuel_percentage=document.getElementById('fuel_percentage').value;
       //var customer_complaint=document.getElementById('customer-complaint').value;
       var serviceType=document.getElementById('serviceType').value;
       var delivery_time=document.getElementById('delivery-time').value;
       var mechanic_name=document.getElementById('mechanic_name').value;
       var total_estimation=document.getElementById('total-estimation').value;

        $.ajax({
    url: "/dealer/details",
     dataType : 'json',
     success: function(data) {
       //called when successful
   //alert(data[0].sunday);
           alert(data.address);
         var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Jobcard</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body ><br><h3 style="text-
      align:center;"></h3><br><hr><br>');
        printWindow.document.write('<h4 style="text-align:center;">Invoice Number: '+jobcard_id+'</h4>');
        printWindow.document.write("<table>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td style='width:300px;'><b><h2>Customer Details:</h2></b></td><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'><b><h2>Vehicle Details:</h2></b></td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td style='width:300px;'>Vehicle Number: "+vehicle_number+"</td><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'>Brand : "+brand+"</td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td style='width:300px;'>Name: "+cust_name+"</td><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'>Model : "+brand+"</h2></td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td style='width:300px;'>Contact Number: "+cont_num+"</td><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'>Kilometers: "+kms+"</td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td style='width:300px;'>Address: "+cont_addr+"</td><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'>Toolkit: "+tol_kit+"</td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'></td><td style='width:300px;'>Fuel Percentage: "+fuel_percentage+"</td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td><br><br></td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("</table><br><table cellpadding='20' cellspacing='20' border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>");
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><th>SERIVICE TYPE</th><th>CUSTOMER COMPLAINTS</th><th>MECHANIC NAME</th></tr>");        
        printWindow.document.write("<tr><td>"+serviceType+"</td><td>"+customer_complaint+"</td><td>"+mechanic_name+"</td></tr>");
        printWindow.document.write("</table><br><br><br>Estimated Delivery Time: "+delivery_time+"<br><br>Estimated Price: "+total_estimation+" INR<br><br><br><br><br><Br><hr>");
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
  },
     error: function(e) {
//called when there is an error
console.log(e.message);
         }
             });

   }
```

Comment: Have you tried instead change function `myFunction() { };` for `var myFunction = { }` and then transfer the value of the variable to AJAX? You forgot something too specify the method `type: "POST"` of entry into your AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the new window popup on success? I think there is a line break here which causes a runtime error

```
 style=text-

   align:center
```

Also, looks like you are not using the 'data' response in the success handler? You need to wait for the html populated  with the 'data' values before declaring all the variables that you're binding to in the print html.